# Setting notification/alarm in an android application

Tags: android, notifications

I am building a simple android app for java tutorial in which i want to keep one read later option using which the user can schedule a time for reading and at the specified time my app should give a notification to the user. Even if my app is not opened at that time he should get the notification in notifications bar.I am a newbie in android and have no idea about how to do this.Can someone please help me out?As a i am a newbie a detailed explanation can be more helpful.Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I recommend as starting point visit http://goo.gl/mR2d, if you have specific question about your code or implementation, please ask us :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To schedule a delayed notification, you

1) Create a `BroadcastReceiver` that will receive the event:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //you might want to check what's inside the Intent
        if(intent.getStringExtra("myAction") != null &&
                intent.getStringExtra("myAction").equals("notify")){
            NotificationManager manager =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.yourIcon)
                    //example for large icon
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setContentTitle("my title")
                    .setContentText("my message")
                    .setOngoing(false)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, YourTargetActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            context,
                            0,
                            i,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                    );
            // example for blinking LED
            builder.setLights(0xFFb71c1c, 1000, 2000);
            builder.setSound(yourSoundUri);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            manager.notify(12345, builder.build());
        }

    }
}
```

Don't forget to declare it in the Manifest:

```
       <receiver
        android:name="your.package.name.MyReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />
```

2) Schedule the action (assumed you do it from an `Activity`):

```
   //will fire in 60 seconds
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000L;

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("myAction", "mDoNotify");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pendingIntent);
```

3) You're done

//Disclaimer: haven't compiled the code, typos possible. The rest is your homework ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `AlarmManager` to solve your problem. And when alarm is received, you can send a notification too.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) sample app in android's tutorial for implementing the alarms.